# Navigating two charts on one screen

Tags: ios, info-visualisation, charts

I want to display two charts on one page and have similar chart navigation and examination experience as iOS Apple Health app does. The issue is that Apple Heath has only one chart on the page but with two charts it becomes confusing how to properly use date navigation controls.

**Option 1**

Have one date navigation control that controls two charts and when a user scrolls horizontally one of the charts - dates in the control change accordingly.
*Pros:* More space is left for charts, one control reduces the clutter.
*Cons:* While scrolling one chart it might get confusing why the other one scrolls.

**Option 2**

Have two independent date navigation controls. 
*Pros:* Separate controls make scrolling and control of individual charts less confusing. 
*Cons:* Less space is left for charts, more cluttered UI.

**Option 3**

Have one date navigation control and tabs that switch the chart. 
*Pros:* One chart at a time with one date navigation. 
*Cons:* Other chart is hidden, difficult to compare two charts.

[image: Different options of chart display]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 4

Since you want to show the 2 charts, I am assuming the user's motivation is to compare multiple datasets over a period of time.

As sessions and time duration are closely connected I feel putting them together on a single chart will provide more inferential insights.

[image]

#### Pros

1. Contextual data at the same place
2. Easy to identify a trend

#### Cons

1. Confuse users with 2 axis
2. Dense display of data

Answer (score 0):

For me the first version makes most sense.

Having individual date date-selections per chart (version 2) makes it confusing if you want to compare charts and they can view different dates. Why would you view sessions of day X and time of Y at the same time?

If it's only those two charts, why not display them right away? Collapsing them (version 3) removes the ability to compare

Answer (score 0):

Or you could have both version 1 and version 4 that @tridip1931 posted, with a way of switching between the two, but imho if there's no real reason to not have the charts combined, I would go with version 4 alone.